# Undefined reference to function in g++ while using static linking on Linux

Tags: c++, g++

I am learning programming under Linux, and I faced the following problem during linking.

#### My directory structure

```
libraries
    |-- archive_sample
    |           |-- calc.h
    |           |-- calc.cpp
    |           |-- makefile
    |
    |-- test_archive
                |-- main.cpp
                |-- makefile
```

#### calc.h

```
#ifndef __CALC__H__
#define __CALC__H__

int add(int a, int b);
int sub(int a, int b);

#endif
```

#### calc.cpp

```
#include "calc.h"

int add(int a, int b)
{
  return (a + b);
}

int sub(int a, int b)
{
  return (a - b);
}
```

#### File archive_sample/makefile:

```
libcalc.a : calc.o
    ar rcs libcalc.a calc.o

calc.o : calc.cpp calc.h
    g++ $(CFLAGS) -c calc.cpp

clean :
    rm -f libcalc.a calc.o
```

When I run "make" from archive_sample directory, it executes successfully and calc.o and libcalc.a are created in the same directory.

#### main.cpp

```
int main()
{
  int a, b;

  std::cin >> a >> b;
  std::cout << "a + b : " << add(a, b) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "a - b : " << sub(a, b) << std::endl;

  return (0);
}
```

Compiling with

```
g++ -c -I../archive_sample main.cpp
```

succeeds and main.o is created. However linking with

```
g++ -L../archive_sample -lcalc main.o -o test
```

gives the following error:

```
main.o: In function main:
main.cpp:(.text+0x3e): undefined reference to add(int, int)
main.cpp:(.text+0x84): undefined reference to sub(int, int)
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Where am I going wrong?

Also "make" is also not working for the following makefile.

#### test_archive/makefile

```
test : main.o
    g++ -L../archive_sample -lcalc main.o

main.o : main.cpp calc.h
    g++ $(CFLAGS) -c -I../archive_sample main.cpp

clean :
    rm -f test *.o
```

with error

```
make: *** No rule to make target `calc.h', needed by `main.o'.  Stop.
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Libraries go **after** the objects that depend on them on the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first error, since `main.cpp` and `archive_sample` are in the same directory, you shouldn't specify `-Larchive_sample` rather than `-L../archive_sample`.

For the second error, your `calc.h` is in the `archive_sample` directory, so the dependency should be listed as `archive_sample/calc.h`.

Comment: also I had to specify library after the objects as said by Mat.